# Cell for cell match instead of value for value match

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Optimally, I would have it done with an excel formula, but if it isn't possible, I'd also accept a User Defined Function as solution.

Consider this screenshot:

[image]

**Though the match formulas `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$12,0)),"No Match", "Match")` in the Column C seem to be working perfectly, they have one caveat for me: They display "Match" even if there are two `4` in the Lookup Cells Column for only one `4` in the Lookup Range Column.**

**Is there, in excel, a function or a combination of them that would do a cell for cell match instead of a value for value match?**

For instance, in the example above, the `4` in the 5th row should not display "Match". Rather, it should display "No Match".

Now, as I've stated at the beginning of the question, if it isn't possible with excel functions, I'll instead make do with `UDFS`.

The algorithm, that I've not yet finished writing in the form of vba code, is one that has 3 arguments: the lookup cell, the lookup cells and the lookup range. The function output is "Match" or "No Match".

Basically, if I take the example above, the lookup cell *could be* A2, the lookup cells, $A$2:$A$5 and the lookup range, $B$2:$B$12.

With the lookup cells and the lookup range, I create two arrays, one for each.

Afterwards, compare their values in a loop. If one of their values are the same, *I add their value to another array* along with *their relative row within the lookup range column* and *their absolute row number within the Lookup Cells column.* This array is dynamic and has two dimensions.

Then, I would (stuck at this part) have another loop comparing the values from the lookup cells to the values within the array. If they are equal, then I'd like for the Lookup Range loop to start its loop after the relative row of this value stored in the array (+1).

Finally, after looping through it all and finding which cells do match (values in the array), if one of the absolute row numbers in the array coincide with the absolute row number of the lookup cell (1st argument of the function), then the function returns "Match". If not, it returns "No Match".

My thanks and my unfinished code below:

```
Function Rlookup(ByVal LookupCell As Range, ByVal LookupCells, ByVal LookupRange)

Dim LookupRngArray As Variant
Dim LookupCellsArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim w As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim Arr() As Variant

x = 0

LookupRngArray = LookupRange.Value2
LookupCellsArray = LookupCells.Value2

For i = 1 To UBound(LookupCellsArray)

    For z = 1 To UBound(LookupRngArray)

        If LookupCellsArray(i, 1) = LookupRngArray(z, 1) Then

            For y = x To 0 Step -1

                If LookupCells(i, 1) = Arr(1, y + 1) Then
                    z > Arr(1, y + 1)

                    Else

                    x = x + 1
                    ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To 3, 1 To x)
                    Arr(1, x) = LookupCellsArray(i, 1)
                    Arr(2, x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(LookupCellsArray(i, 1), LookupRngArray, 0)
                    Arr(3, x) = LookupCells.Row + i - 1

                End If

            Next y

        End If

    Next z

Next i

For w = 1 To x

If LookupCell.Row = Arr(3, w) Then
Rlookup = "Match"

End If
Next

If Rlookup = "0" Then Rlookup = "No Match"
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done with COUNTIF():

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)<=COUNTIF(B:B,A2),"match","No Match"),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like I started a UDF for nothing, thanks for the lead. I'll look into it

Comment: @ScottCraner The only issue I'm noticing is that your formula is returning "Match" for a blank entry in column A when Sam is looking to have it display "No Match" like in their example - looks like you'll just need to check to make sure the cell isn't blank?

Comment: @Scott Craner Both formulas work great except that the latter has one advantage: it displays "No Match" with blank cells whereas the 2nd one does not.

Comment: @Sam Although I'm sure Scott is about to fix it, the amended formula would be `=IF(A2<>"",IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)<=COUNTIF(B:B,A2),"Match","No Match"),"No Match")`.

Comment: @dwirony Thanks for the amended formula

Comment: @Sam would you rather it return blank or `no match` when column A is blank

Comment: @ScottCraner Blank would be better. Thanks btw