# Cell for cell match and return offset cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**With the countif formula that I've received from this question: [Cell for cell match instead of value for value match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883394/cell-for-cell-match-instead-of-value-for-value-match), is there a formula retains the cell for cell match property as countif does AND, that outputs an offset cell from the lookup range, if there is indeed a match?**

Consider this scenario:
[image]
In this example, the formula:

`=IF(B2<>"",IF(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)<=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$7,B2),"Match",""),"")` in cells `C4 and C5` is matching for amounts that coincide with amounts in range `E2 to E7` and returns `"Match"` if there indeed is a match.

By replacing the output string `"Match"` with an Index - Match formula, I obtain an almost perfect formula that does return an offset cell from the lookup range.
`=IF(B2<>"",IF(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2<=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$7,B2),INDEX($D$2:$D$6,MATCH(B2,$E$2:$E$7,0)),""),"")`

[image]

**You may notice however, that it returns `"xxxx McDonalds"` in cell `C3` instead of `"xxxx Subway"` and that, is the problem.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be simplified with the use of AGGREGATE to:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($E$2:$E$7)/($E$2:$E$7=B2),COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2))),"no match")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again! Will look into

Comment: Just one question. I tried to modify the function to accept partial matches and it doesn't work. Any ideas? `=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$2:$D$7)/($D$2:$D$7="*"&A2&"*"),COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2))),"")` The cell in which I enter the formula returns nothing

Comment: You will need to use `(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,$D$2:$D$7)))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Will do